# StackPanel with the Surface API - never any TouchesCapturedWithin

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, touch, pixelsense

I've been trying to create a visual for dragging and dropping a `StackPanel` in WPF on the TouchDown event. I've  managed to do this already for a `SurfaceListBoxItem` with no problem but not for a `StackPanel`. I've narrowed it down to the fact that the `TouchesCapturedWithin` property for the `SurfaceListBoxItem` is 1 (as it should be) but is always 0 for a `StackPanel` (even when looking at this property in the `TouchDown` event handler for the `StackPanel`).

```
    private void stackPanel1_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<TouchDevice> touches = (sender as StackPanel).TouchesCapturedWithin;
    }
```

I need this `IEnumerable` further on in the code so I'm assuming that this is why I can't see anything when dragging.

Thanks a lot,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it using TouchesOver property instead.